# How to use IN clause within JOIN condition

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run a query but getting a syntax error.

I want to know if the following code is somehow possible. Here is my code:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM someTable t1 LEFT JOIN someTable t2 ON t2.comeColumn IN (9, 8) WHERE t1.ID in (248, 226)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use column index by `IN` clause? Put few sample data then desired output.

Comment: Can't JOIN to IN() clause. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. You want to self-join table?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.*, t3.* 
FROM 
    someTable t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (Select * From someTable t2 
    Where t2.comeColumn In (9, 8)) t3
    ON t2.comeColumn = t1.ID
WHERE
    t1.ID in (248, 226)
```